# Bloomberg C# API - How to Call BDP with different options/Fields

Tags: bloomberg

I am trying to migrate from Excel add-in to Bloomberg C# Desktop API. For simple calls like BDP("AB IB Equity","best_analyst_rating") I am able to do without issues using something like this:

```
    private void sendRefDataRequest(Session session)
    {            
        Service refDataService = session.GetService("//blp/refdata");
        Request request = refDataService.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest");

        // Add securities to request
        Element securities = request.GetElement("securities");
        securities.AppendValue("AB IB Equity");
        Element fields = request.GetElement("fields");
        fields.AppendValue("best_analyst_rating");
        System.Console.WriteLine("Sending Request: " + request);
        session.SendRequest(request, null);
    }
```

But for more complex calls involving additional options to BDP like 
BDP("AB IB Equity","bs_tot_asset","EQY_Consolidated","Y","EQY_FUND_Relative_Period","-0FY") I have no clue how to translate it to C# calls. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the overrides. For any given field you can find these using FLDS in the Bloomberg terminal.

```
Element overrides = request.GetElement("overrides");
```

Then loop through the necessary overrides, setting the fieldId to the Mnemonic from FLDS and the value to your specific request:

```
Element override = overrides.AppendElement();
override.SetElement("fieldId","EQY_CONSOLIDATED");
override.SetElement("value","Y");
```

Comment: just fyi for anyone who finds this -- make sure you properly capitalize SetElement

Answer (score 1):

I created an extension method for this:

```
public static void AddOverride(this Bloomberglp.Blpapi.Request request, string fieldId, string fieldValue)
{
    var override = request["overrides"].AppendElement();
    override.SetElement("fieldId",fieldId);
    override.SetElement("value", fieldValue);
}
```